# finding not a strings regex python3

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I try to build something that would check code.
how can I build a regex that would find for example only double spaces not at the beginning
of a line, and not between uneven number of `"`.
for example:

```
print(",  ,",  "l")
```

will only find the double spacing between `,` and `"`
so it can be splited into two problems:

1. not at the beginning (`^` is beginning, but the not is the problem isn't `^` also not?)
2. not between uneven number of `"`.
   thank you

Comment: Language or tool you are using ?

Comment: `^` means not when its inside a character class `[^x]` otherwise it matches the start of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

code = r"""
    print(",  ,",  "l")   # comment  spaces
    print(",  ,",  "l")   # comment  spaces
"""

print(re.sub(r"""
      [Rr]("(?!"")|'(?!'')|"{3}|'{3}).*?\1          # Raw strings
    | ("(?!"")|'(?!'')|"{3}|'{3})(?:\\.|[^\\])*?\2  # Normal strings
    | [ \t]*\#[^\r\n]*                              # Comments
    | ^[ \t]+                                       # Leading whitespace
    | [ \t]+$                                       # Trailing whitespace
    | ([ \t]{2,})                                   # Duplicate whitespace
""",
lambda m: m.group(0) if m.group(3) is None else ' ',
code,
flags = re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE))
```

**Output:**

```
    print(",  ,", "l")   # comment  spaces
    print(",  ,", "l")   # comment  spaces
```

http://ideone.com/3ouQee

We need to match, and discard, all the other patterns, so we don't get any false positives. The only places where the double-space can occur (and we don't want to replace it) is inside strings, in comments, and at the start end end of lines.

- **The first line** of the pattern matches Python raw strings, both single and double-quoted, both normal and multi-line. All characters are allowed, except for the quote-sequence that started the string.
- **The second line** matches normal Python strings (non-raw), both single and double-quoted, both normal and multi-line. Escaped (`\"`) characters are skipped. Otherwise all characters except backslash (`\`) and the quote-sequence that started the string.
- **The third line** matches comments, and any leading white-space.
- **The fourth and fifth lines** matches leading and trailing white-space. You could remove the fifth line, if you wish to trim trailing white-space also.
- **The last line** matches what we actually want to replace; Two or more spaces in sequence.

The replacement is not a string, but a lambda-function that checks if the third group exists (the last line in the pattern). If not, it is replaced with the full match (no change). If the group exists, it is replaced with a single space.